# First load of my page doesn't quite work

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading

I am somewhat new to jQuery and javascript and just implemented a new code yesterday to handle some styling around my menu.  When the homepage loads, it doesn't quite work right, although it is doing something.  When I navigate away to another page and come back, it works fine.  It's that first load that's giving me grief.  Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong with my code?

Here's my code:

```
$(function(){ 
  var url = window.location.pathname,  
      urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$");
    $('.nav ul li a').each(function(){  
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){        
        $(this).attr('id', 'selected'); 
        } 
  });
    $(function() {
        if (url === "/index.html" || url === "/") {
        $('.nav').attr('id','homenav');
        }
  });
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with the first load? It's awfully hard to figure out the problem when we don't know the symptoms.

Comment: This is a tricky one... We can't know for sure what's going on, and what's going wrong. You can use "console.log(Object here)" to output various data in the dev console on most modern webbrowsers (Like chrome: Right click on page -> Inspect element -> Console"

Comment: The code is supposed to detect the file path and if it matches the href attribute in the anchor tag, then it adds an id to the list item that contains that particular anchor.  It changes that text from black to blue, essentially.  On first load, it changes all the list items to blue.  When I navigate away and come back, the function appears to be running just fine.

Comment: So the first time it loads, every link in the navigation passes the RegExp test somehow?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right @Barney.  Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Hmm. Can you paste your HTML for the `.nav` in? And give us a simple URI you're trying this on? (Not a live one — just something we can use to replicate the test conditions)

Comment: console.log what the href is in each case to see what the differences are, then figure out why they are different on first compared to second. shouldn't be too hard to debug.

Comment: Well on first load, it goes to the pathname: "/".  When I navigate away and come back, it's sending me to pathname: "/index.html".  When I go back to "/", there's the problem.  So it's not a first load problem.  It's an issue with my RegExp test when it runs "/" as the url.  Any thoughts with the RegExp test? It's borrowed code and I'm not sure how to REALLY translate it into english--not that advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the problem is just that when its `/` which is the same page as `/index.html` why not make `/` `/index.html` before the check.. like so:

```
$(function(){ 
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    if(url == '/')
    {
        url = '/index.html'; 
    }
    var urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$");
    $('.nav ul li a').each(function(){  
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){        
            $(this).attr('id', 'selected'); 
        } 
    });

    $(function() {
        if (url === "/index.html") {
            $('.nav').attr('id','homenav');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Smart Idea.  I tried that out and it works.  I guess I need to work on thinking more creatively about solutions rather than getting too detailed.  Thanks, Danny.

Answer (score 0):

You must wrap your javascript inside theready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(function(){ 
  var url = window.location.pathname,  
      urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$");
    $('.nav ul li a').each(function(){  
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){        
        $(this).attr('id', 'selected'); 
        } 
  });
    $(function() {
        if (url === "/index.html" || url === "/") {
        $('.nav').attr('id','homenav');
        }
  });
});
});
```

I think.

that's all folks

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { } is equal to $(function() {} in jQuery.  So that's not it, but thanks for trying!